# Using Shared Preference to show specific items in listview

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing, sharedpreferences

I have a Rss feed that I am parsing into a list view.  What I am trying to do with it is when the user first loads the app, it saves the date or something like that and then only shows Day One of the list.  Then when the user logs in the second day it remembers that date from the preference and adds one to it and shows Day One and Day Two in the list view and so forth and so forth.  Also, if the user doesn't open the app for a few days it needs to show the days that the user missed as well.  For Example, user opens app day one, and day two and sees those articles, then doesn't open the app till day 5, they would still need to see days 1-5 in the list.  I am thinking that I can do all this with Shared Preference, however I haven't worked with shared preferences any and haven't found any tutorials that would cover anything I am trying to do here.  I will list my code here that I am using.  If anyone is willing to work through this issue with me I would greatly appreciate it.

xml parsing activity and listview

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.cpcofc.org/devoapp.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "item";
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_GUID = "guid";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
        map.put(KEY_GUID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_GUID));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e,KEY_LINK));


        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_DESC, KEY_NAME, KEY_COST, KEY_GUID}, new int[] {
                    R.id.desciption, R.id.name, R.id.cost});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    Collections.reverse(menuItems);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(menuItems.get(position).get(KEY_GUID));

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);

            // **NEED TO PASS STRING OBJECT NOT URI OBJECT**
            in.putExtra(KEY_GUID, uriUrl.toString());
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
}
```

and here is a view of what it looks like now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the document of SharedPreferences, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html, i think what you need in this case is simply get/put values to SharedPreferences, e.g.

```
public static String getPreference(Application application, String key) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
        return preference.getString(key, "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ""
    }
}

public static void putPreference(Application application, String key, String value) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
        preference.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("...", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Manipulate SharedPreference is simple, but to implement your requirement you need to think how to design the key of SharedPreferences.

A quick thought is that the key can be formed as 'post-20130101', 'post-20130102', etc. In this case, you can put the date string into key, when you want to fetch rss data within a period, you can then build corresponding keys. And you can try SharedPreferences.getAll() to fetch all data and then filter based on date in memory.

However, i think another choice is to use sqlite database. Using sql to filter on date column is more suitable for this kind of requirement in my opinion.

Comment: would you be willing to take this to a chat and help me work through this.  I would really like to understand how this works better and I have read the tutorials but they only seem to help if I want a user to log in, it really doesn't help me with this situation